# Pandas Read csv function not alleging column headers well

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with no headers. The first column  is ID and so on... Here is how I read that file in pandas.

```
rss_content=pd.read_csv("rss_content.csv",header=None,names=["id","feedId","url","imageUrl","title","desc","author","createTimestamp"])
```

However when the file gets imported I see the first two columns of the data become index and the Id column gets assigned to third column and so on. Basically the headers are shifted by two columns to right and first two columns have no header.

Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: Why is this being down voted?

Comment: What's the number of data columns ?

Comment: Only have 8 columns which is what I added in Names

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the following CSV file:

```
1,2,3,4,5
11,22,33,44,55
```

If you specify too less column names the rest columns will become index columns:

```
In [1]: fn = r'D:\temp\.data\41066716.csv'

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv(fn, header=None, names=['a','b','c'])

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
        a   b   c
1  2    3   4   5
11 22  33  44  55
```

Comment: I only have 8 columns. Which is what I added in names

Comment: @Baktaawar, pleas read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Problem is I can't show the data here otherwise I would have presented some snapshot of the data. I always do that

Comment: @Baktaawar, i guess you didn't read the topic i've posted in my comment, did you? Posting __sample__ (not your real data), but reproducible example data set is very important for being able to help you...